# Align page numbering beyond textwidth

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, alignment

I manage to put the page numbering beyond the limits of textwidth with this code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{Autor \thepage }}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{ \thepage \ Obras Escolhidas}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\newlength{\myoddoffset}
\setlength{\myoddoffset}{\marginparwidth + \marginparsep}
\fancyheadoffset[leh,roh]{\marginparsep+8pt}
\fancyheadoffset[loh,reh]{\myoddoffset}

\setcounter{page}{99}
a

\newpage
a
\setcounter{page}{100}
\end{document}
```

but for large page numbers the header became unalign like this.
[image]

[image]

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `\rlap` nad `\llap` plainTeX macros:

```
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{Autor\rlap{ \thepage}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\llap{\thepage\ }Obras Escolhidas}}
```

and don't use the macros concerning to `\myoddoffset`.